# wifi interface unreachable except from pinging pc

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

This is my very weird situation: 
A Zotac Zbox CI320 nano on Win7 should be running 24/7 just feeding a TV with some presentation, accessing stuff from network over Wifi.
Every night, somehow the zbox becomes unreachable EXCEPT from a pc from which we are continuously pinging it. From there, also vnc/rdp and other stuff works.
Logs show nothing relevant because just the "halp, no network stuff available" errors appear.

```
sfc /scannow
```

showed no errors also. Please provide any ideas where to look further. Thanks.

EDIT: Power settings are set to high performance, also, the option to disable the network adapter in order to save power is disabled.

(not sure about asking this on serverfault or here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet multicast is breaking (maybe due to buggy equipment not handling a WPA/WPA2 group key rotation correctly) and ARP request broadcasts aren't getting through to that machine, so ARP replies never get sent back, so machines that aren't constantly pinging lose their ARP table entries for that host, and can never find out its MAC address again.

Next time this happens, go to a machine that can't reach it and look at its ARP table. If there's no ARP entry for that host, enter a static one and see if that machine can reach that host now.

Comment: on a machine that can't reach it: no arp entry. after entering it manually, it is pingable. thank you.